# como hacer una consulta sql para traer los datos que NO sean iguales a los de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

hao  otra vez jeje  estoy intentando traer datos que no estén repetidos en ambas tablas me explico traer los datos donde el id de la tabla 1 no este en la tabla 2
tengo esto

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><b>ID</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Uso</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Acomodacion</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Tipo</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Servicios</b></td>

                                            </tr> 
                        <?php
                                $result=mysqli_query($server,"SELECT beds.* FROM beds, pat_to_bed WHERE beds.bed_id=pat_to_bed.bed_id ORDER BY bed_id DESC");
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
                                    echo"<tr class=odd>
                                        <td>$row[id]</td>
                                        <td>$row[bed_id]</td>
                                        <td>$row[servicio_cam]</td>
                                        <td>$row[acomodacion_cam]</td>
                                        <td>$row[type]</td>
                                        <td>$row[ward]</td>
                                    </tr>";
                                }
                        ?>                       
            </table>
```

de ante mano muchas MUCHAS GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un `NOT IN` lo solucionas

```
SELECT beds.* 
FROM beds
WHERE bed_id not in (SELECT bed_id from pat_to_bed) 
ORDER BY bed_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
SELECT * FROM beds WHERE bed_id NOT IN (
    SELECT bed_id FROM pat_to_bed
  ) ORDER BY bed_id DESC;
```

Por que con:

```
SELECT beds.* FROM beds 
  JOIN pat_to_bed ON beds.bed_id=pat_to_bed.bed_id
  ORDER BY bed_id DESC;
```

Las que traes son precisamente las que están en ambas tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder traer los id que si están en la tabla 1 pero que no están en la tabla 2 deberías poder con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT tablaUno.id, 
       tablaUno.columna2, 
       tablaUno.columna3
FROM tablaUno 
WHERE tablaUno.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM tabla2);
```

- Obtenemos las columnas deseadas de la tabla 1
- Usamos un `WHERE` en conjunto con `NOT IN` para que en la subconsulta indiquemos la selección del id pero de la tabla 2

[Aquí puedes leer mas al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-in)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `NOT EXISTS`, seria algo asi:

```
SELEC * FROM BEDS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PAT_TO_BED WHERE BED_ID = A.BED_ID)
ORDER BY BED_ID DESC
```